# adding legend when plotting with rpy2

Tags: python, legend, rpy2

I am trying to plot an ECDF by using the following commands
But when I run the script I get this error

```
1: In rect(left, top, r, b, angle = angle, density = density, ...) :
  supplied color is not numeric nor character
2: In rect(left, top, r, b, angle = angle, density = density, ...) :
  supplied color is not numeric nor character
```

My code is:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robj
ce=robj.FloatVector(range(1,100,1))
le=robj.FloatVector(range(5,500,2))
label="score"
l1="a"
l2="b"

robj.r["plot.ecdf"](ce,main="",verticals=True,pch=46,col="grey",xlab=label)
robj.r["plot.ecdf"](le,verticals=True,pch=46,col="red",add=True)
robj.r.legend("topleft",legend=[l1,l2],fill=["grey","red"])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This code will fail pretty fast because it's missing the definitions of `ce`, `label`, `le`, and `statistic`. Can you amend it to become [reproducible](http://sscce.org/#selfcon)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Correct the Python lists in your call to `legend`. For example, `fill` should be `fill=robj.StrVector(["grey", "red"])`